# Handling a space in a get parameter

Tags: php, get

I am using a command like

```
 $page = file_get_contents($url);
```

where

```
$url = "http://www.site.com/search/index.cfm?tab=names&workername=firstname lastname";
```

When the url is typed directly in the browser chrome adds a `%20` in between firstname and lastname and the website handles things properly.

However when I use $url with a space, file_get_contents grabs only results that match the firstname and isn't aware that `workername = "firstname lastname"`

When I explicitly add "%20" in between it returns `NULL`...

What's the work around?

Thanks guys!

Comment: have you tried `urlencode()`ing the string in `$url`?

Comment: Enable `error_reporting` and check `$http_response_header` after request.

Answer (score 3):

A few problems:

1. I hope this is just because you quick-typed it here, but you need to have the string in single quotes.
2. There is no query string for the URL because you never start it with the `?`, so no, neither of those variables will exist in `$_GET`.
3. You *do* have to redefine spaces as `%20` for URLs.

---

```
$url = 'http://www.site.com/search/?tab=names&workername=firstname%20lastname';
       ^                           ^                              ^^^        ^
```

---

**Edit:**
It is possible that the website you're trying to query is ignoring them as GET variables. Have you tried adding this code to explicitly say it is a GET request?

```
$options = array(
  'http' => array('method' => "GET", 'header' => "Accept-language: en\r\n")
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: none of these seem to be the problem. I actually have all these things.. largely omitted them due to quick-typing induced errors.. any other thoughts?

Comment: I added an edit, but aside form that I can't think of anything that would cause it to fail for this function. The URL still needs to be encoded with a `%20` though. Are you sure there aren't other characters in the first name or last name that need encoded?

Comment: I'd like top point out that URL-encoding also allows '+' as valid encoding of space characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your text:

```
$fixed= urlencode($workername);
$url = 'http://www.example.com/search/?tab=names&workername='.$fixed;
```